# Test fails when asserting dates

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, testing, xctest

I am trying to verify that two items I am storing are the same. However, while testing I am getting an error when checking a Date property.

Note: my Item class implements the `Equatable` protocol.

This is my setUp method:

```
class InputViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: InputViewController!
    var placemark: MockPlacemark!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",
                                      bundle: nil)
        sut = storyboard
            .instantiateViewController(
                withIdentifier: "InputViewController")
            as! InputViewController
        _ = sut.view
    }
}
```

This is the extension of my test class:

```
extension InputViewControllerTests {
    class MockGeocoder: CLGeocoder {
        var completionHandler: CLGeocodeCompletionHandler?
        override func geocodeAddressString(
            _ addressString: String,
            completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler) {
            self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        }
    }

    class MockPlacemark : CLPlacemark {
        var mockCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
        override var location: CLLocation? {
            guard let coordinate = mockCoordinate else
            { return CLLocation() }
            return CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                              longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
func test_Save_UsesGeocoderToGetCoordinateFromAddress() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        let timestamp = 1456095600.0
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
        sut.titleTextField.text = "Foo"
        sut.dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        sut.locationTextField.text = "Bar"
        sut.addressTextField.text = "Infinite Loop 1, Cupertino"
        sut.descriptionTextField.text = "Baz"
        let mockGeocoder = MockGeocoder()
        sut.geocoder = mockGeocoder
        sut.itemManager = ItemManager()
        sut.save()
        placemark = MockPlacemark()
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.3316851,
                                                    -122.0300674)
        placemark.mockCoordinate = coordinate
        mockGeocoder.completionHandler?([placemark], nil)
        let item = sut.itemManager?.item(at: 0)
        let testItem = ToDoItem(title: "Foo",
                                itemDescription: "Baz",
                                timestamp: timestamp,
                                location: Location(name: "Bar",
                                                   coordinate: coordinate))
        XCTAssertEqual(item, testItem)
    }
```

This is the implementation of the `save()` method:

```
class InputViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
    @IBAction func save() {
        guard let titleString = titleTextField.text,
            titleString.characters.count > 0 else { return }
        let date: Date?
        if let dateText = self.dateTextField.text,
            dateText.characters.count > 0 {
            date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateText)
        } else {
            date = nil
        }
        let descriptionString = descriptionTextField.text
        if let locationName = locationTextField.text,
            locationName.characters.count > 0 {
            if let address = addressTextField.text,
                address.characters.count > 0 {
                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {
                    [unowned self] (placeMarks, error) -> Void in
                    let placeMark = placeMarks?.first
                    let item = ToDoItem(
                        title: titleString,
                        itemDescription: descriptionString,
                        timestamp: date?.timeIntervalSince1970,
                        location: Location(
                            name: locationName,
                            coordinate: placeMark?.location?.coordinate))
                    self.itemManager?.add(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble trying to figure out what is wrong with this. The error I am getting is:

> test_Save_UsesGeocoderToGetCoordinateFromAddress()] failed: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(ToDo.ToDoItem(title: "Foo", itemDescription: Optional("Baz"), timestamp: Optional(1456030800.0), location: Optional(ToDo.Location(name: "Bar", coordinate: Optional(__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.331685100000001, longitude: -122.03006739999999))))))") is not equal to ("Optional(ToDo.ToDoItem(title: "Foo", itemDescription: Optional("Baz"), timestamp: Optional(1456095600.0), location: Optional(ToDo.Location(name: "Bar", coordinate: Optional(__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.331685100000001, longitude: -122.03006739999999))))))") -

As it can be clearly seen, the problem is that the timestamp is not the same in both, and I have no idea why it is changing.

**EDIT:** As @ganzogo found, there is a difference of exactly 18 hours between this too items. I am living in Ecuador which is GTM-5. Perhaps this could be a cue to figure out the problem.

Comment: With `XCTAssertEqual` you can check equality of object's addresses. But your `item` and `testItem` not the same.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov, note that as I am saying everything is the same, but the `tiemestamp` property, and I do not know why since I am using `1456095600.0` to create both. Actually, notice that `item` is  1456030800.0, while `testItem` is 1456095600.0. I have no idea why the the value of item is changing.

Comment: and btw @ArtemNovichkov, I thought you were able to check equality whenever a class implements the protocol `Equatable`, and my Item class does.

Comment: The difference is exactly 18 hours, so I suspect it's a time zone issue.

Comment: @ganzogo, you are right. It is constant difference of 18 hours. I am living in Ecuador which is GMT-5. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You first need to decide whether the `testItem` or the `item` is showing the correct time, then you need to adjust the other one by manually passing through a time zone. The unit tests will run on a simulator or device and classes like `DateFormatter ` will use the device's time zone by default, so you need to override that.

Comment: @ganzogo, I guess I get your point, but if you can provide any answer with an example, I will be very thankful.

Comment: Okay - have given it a go.

Answer (score 1):

After your line:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
```

Try this:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 64800)
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -64800)
```

:-)

But you're kind of defeating the purpose of a unit test if you're just hacking it until in passes. You really need to understand whether the `testItem` or the `item` is exhibiting the correct behaviour right now, and that will depend on your application.

Comment: I have tried both, but none worked. When I tried the first one there is still a difference of six hours. I have tried added 6 hours, but now I have a difference of 18 hours again.

Comment: I have even tried changing the location, but again it is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

In func 
`test_Save_UsesGeocoderToGetCoordinateFromAddress()`
timestamp transform to sut.dateTextField.text，then 
In sut.save()
`sut.dateTextField.text` 
transform to timestamp, the minute and second are drop